# How to center header using css?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have created a navbar menu using flex box , no framework , only html and csss 
no bootstrap or foundation
Here is what I want to look like :\

[image]
here is html:

```css
ul,
nav {
  list-style: none;
}

.Navbar {
  display: flex;
  padding: 16px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: white;
  background-color: orange;
}

.Navbar__Link {
  padding-right: 30px;
  font-family: ProximaNova;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #fff;
}

.Navbar__Items {
  display: flex;
}

.Navbar__Items--right {
  margin-left: auto;
}

.Navbar__Link-toggle {
  display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .Navbar__Items,
  .Navbar {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .Navbar__Items {
    display: none;
  }
  .Navbar__Items--right {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  .Navbar__ToggleShow {
    display: flex;
  }
  .Navbar__Link-toggle {
    align-self: flex-end;
    display: initial;
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="Navbar">
    <div class="Navbar__Link Navbar__Link-brand">
      Dronezone
    </div>
    <div class="Navbar__Link Navbar__Link-toggle">
      <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
    </div>
    <nav class="Navbar__Items Navbar__Items--right">
      <div class="Navbar__Link">
        Home
      </div>
      <div class="Navbar__Link">
        About
      </div>
      <div class="Navbar__Link">
        Pricing
      </div>
      <div class="Navbar__Link">
        Our drones
      </div>
      <div class="Navbar__Link">
        Our Realization
      </div>
      <div class="Navbar__Link">
        Contact
      </div>


    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

here is jsfidle : http://jsfiddle.net/jyc7Lkh4/
Note: Itried margin but I have problem when trying responsiveness

what do I need to change to get what I want?

Answer (score 0):

To centered the NAVIGATION here. You should assign a specific width for your .Navbar (which is in this modification I made is that I assigned it into width: 960px; and add the margin: 0 auto; to centered position it. I also transfer the background into the HEADER.)

```css
ul,
nav {
  list-style: none;
}
/* Changes I Make */
header {
  background-color: orange;
}

.Navbar {
  display: flex;
  padding: 16px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: white;
  width: 960px; /* Added Code */
  margin: 0 auto; /* Added Code */
}

.Navbar__Link {
  padding-right: 30px;
  font-family: ProximaNova;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #fff;
}

.Navbar__Items {
  display: flex;
}

.Navbar__Items--right {
  margin-left: auto;
}

.Navbar__Link-toggle {
  display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .Navbar__Items,
  .Navbar {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .Navbar__Items {
    display: none;
  }
  .Navbar__Items--right {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  .Navbar__ToggleShow {
    display: flex;
  }
  .Navbar__Link-toggle {
    align-self: flex-end;
    display: initial;
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="Navbar">
    <div class="Navbar__Link Navbar__Link-brand">
      Dronezone
    </div>
    <div class="Navbar__Link Navbar__Link-toggle">
      <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
    </div>
    <nav class="Navbar__Items Navbar__Items--right">
      <div class="Navbar__Link">
        Home
      </div>
      <div class="Navbar__Link">
        About
      </div>
      <div class="Navbar__Link">
        Pricing
      </div>
      <div class="Navbar__Link">
        Our drones
      </div>
      <div class="Navbar__Link">
        Our Realization
      </div>
      <div class="Navbar__Link">
        Contact
      </div>


    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: set static width I dont know if its good solution for mobile first design

Comment: I give you a theory of how could you achieved that design similar to the one you show to us. Now, mobile first design solution is a different question. So, for me, to make this things work. This is what I'm going to do.

.Navbar { max-width: 960px; width: 90%; margin: 0 auto; }

So, to explain this layout. max-width: 960px is the limit of the width of the Navbar even if your screen is more than 960px.

Next is width: 90%, this will start once the width of the browser you used is less than 960px. I used 90% for the trick of the both margin-left and margin-right for your navigation.

Answer (score 0):

Move `background-color: orange` from `.Navbar` to `header`.

You should also think about changing the naming convention for you class names. They are typically lowercase and use dashes between words e.g. `navbar-link` rather than `Navbar__Link`, although it more important to ensure that naming conventions are consistent across the whole project.

```
body {
    position: relative;
}

header {
    background-color: orange;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
}

.Navbar {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,0);
}
```

Comment: did you test your solution??? this does not work and , am using my own convetion name (bem) so no problem about that, but u code is not what I asked , thanks for help though

Answer (score 0):

```css
ul,
nav {
  list-style: none;
}
header {
    position: relative;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(202, 12, 12,1), rgba(255,0,0,1));
}
.Navbar {
    display: flex;
    padding: 16px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: white;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.Navbar__Link {
  padding-right: 30px;
  font-family: ProximaNova;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #fff;
}

.Navbar__Items {
  display: flex;
}

.Navbar__Items--right {
  margin-left: auto;
}

.Navbar__Link-toggle {
  display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .Navbar__Items,
  .Navbar {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .Navbar__Items {
    display: none;
  }
  .Navbar__Items--right {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  .Navbar__ToggleShow {
    display: flex;
  }
  .Navbar__Link-toggle {
    align-self: flex-end;
    display: initial;
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="Navbar">
    <div class="Navbar__Link Navbar__Link-brand">
      Dronezone
    </div>
    <div class="Navbar__Link Navbar__Link-toggle">
      <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
    </div>
    <nav class="Navbar__Items Navbar__Items--right">
      <div class="Navbar__Link">
        Home
      </div>
      <div class="Navbar__Link">
        About
      </div>
      <div class="Navbar__Link">
        Pricing
      </div>
      <div class="Navbar__Link">
        Our drones
      </div>
      <div class="Navbar__Link">
        Our Realization
      </div>
      <div class="Navbar__Link">
        Contact
      </div>


    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution please just litle explanation for your work to make others also understand what u have done :)